# Ajax in Wordpress form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm following the page here - http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#admin-ajax

So I have a simple form

```
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

In `functions.php` I have

```
    // embed the javascript file that makes the AJAX request
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/compiled/main.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );

    function myajax_submit() {
        // get the submitted parameters
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        // generate the response
        $response = json_encode( array( 'success' =&gt; true ) );

        // response output
        header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        echo $response;

        // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
        exit;
    }
```

I'm using grunt to concatenate my js files which are then minified to `/js/compiled/main.min.js`
This minified file includes the js to validate the form and the post function.

The js

```
    $atj(function(){
      $atj('.js-training').click(function(e) {
        //
        e.preventDefault();

        if(verfiyTrainingFields()) {
          $atj.post(
            MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
              action : 'myajax-submit',
              firstName : $atj("#name").val(), 
              email : $atj("#email").val(), 
            },
            function(response){
              alert(response);
            }
          )
        }
      });
    })


    //Verfiy 
    function verfiyTrainingFields() {
      var flag = true;

      var name =        $atj('#name');
      var email =       $atj('#email');

      if(name.val().indexOf(' ') === -1 ){
        name.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter name, first space last</p>');
        fadeOut();
        flag = false;
      }
      if(!IsEmail(email.val())){
        email.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter valid email address</p>');
        fadeOut();
        flag = false;
      }
      return flag;
    }
```

I'm getting an error in the console

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: MyAjax is not defined
```

**UPDATE**

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

    function add_my_script() {
        wp_register_script('scripts',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/compiled/main.min.js', array('jquery'),1 ,true);
        wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
        //
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/compiled/main.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
    }
```

Comment: For starters, put your `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` in a function hooked to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: I've added wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script to the function I use to load jQuery - I've UPDATED my question to show the code - I'm still getting the same error in the console